# dynamically generated form not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, dynamic

im having this ajax function where i populate a list of elements coming from the database dynamically. Each one of them as a display pic and a name. It has a hidden field with a variable that is being caught on the other page via POST and displays an image and some info with it.

The problem is that sometimes the ID parameter in the hidden field doesnt seem to be sent. the form is sent but it doesnt seem to catch the hidden variable, displaying a random image and info instead of the one that im initially clicking.

here is my code:

```
function absurdSearch(textoBuscar){
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "service.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data    : {
            action:"absurdSearch",
            absurdText: textoBuscar
        },
        success:function(data){
            $("#testDiv").empty();
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; ++i) {

                console.log(data);
                var divCreator ='';
                var str='projectsearch' + i;

                data.data[i].projectCategory

                var ProjectTypeIdName = data.data[i].projectCategory;
                switch (ProjectTypeIdName) {
                    case "1":
                        var urlFormSend='proyectos_arq.php';
                        var projectTypeName ='Proyectos <br/>Arquitectónicos';
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        var urlFormSend='proyectos_urb.php';
                        var projectTypeName ='Proyectos <br/>Urbanos';
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        var urlFormSend='arquit_pai.php';
                        var projectTypeName ='Arquitectura del <br/>Paisaje';
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        var urlFormSend='arquit_int.php';
                        var projectTypeName ='Arquitectura de <br/>Interiores';
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        var urlFormSend='arquit_trans.php';
                        var projectTypeName ='Arquitectura del <br/>Transporte';
                        break;
                }

                divCreator+='<div id="grupo'+i+' class="typeface-js" style="font-family:GreyscaleBasic"">';
                divCreator+='<div class="tipo-pro">';
                divCreator+='<div id="tipo_arq" class="tipo">'+projectTypeName+'</div>';
                divCreator+='<div id="tipo_arq_abajo" class="abajo"></div>';
                divCreator+='</div>';
                divCreator+='<div>';
                divCreator+='<div id="tipo_'+i+'"></div>';
                divCreator+='<div id="tipo_arq_abajo'+i+'"></div>';
                divCreator+='</div>';
                divCreator+='<div id="fotoproyectos'+i+'" ><img src="' + data.data[i].path + '" height="128" width="160"></div>';
                divCreator+='<div id="nombreproyectos'+i+'" ><form method="post" name="projectsearch'+i+'" id="projectsearch'+ i +'" action="'+urlFormSend+'">';
                divCreator+='<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById(\'projectsearch'+i+'\').submit()">"'+ data.data[i].projectName +'"</span>'
                divCreator+='<input name="project_id" type="hidden" id="project_id" value="' + data.data[i].projectId + '">';
                divCreator+='</form></div>';
                divCreator+='</div>';
                divCreator+='</div><br><br>';

                $("#testDiv").append(divCreator);

            };
        }
    })
};
```

and here is the code that actually catches the POST variable.

```
<?php
require('server/php/methods.php');
$main = new main();
$project_id = $_POST['project_id'];
if (empty($project_id)) {
    list($name, $description, $path, $_images, $next_project_id, $previous_project_id = $main->projectRandom(7);
    $images = json_encode($_images);
}
else {
    list($name, $description, $path, $_images, $next_project_id, $previous_project_id) = $main->projectNumber(7, $project_id);
    $images = json_encode($_images);
}
```

when i check on firebug everything seems to be ok, every hidden field has the parameter (project_id) assigned. But sometimes it does work and sometimes it doesnt.

Firebug:

[image: Firebug]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: *Hint:* In your script, don't do two things at once, better check the request's input is the expected one for the action. That will allow you to move away from random to distinct action. Here you do two things at once, and when the variable is empty, you pick a random image which seems to be what you describe as an error however it is the programmed functionality.

Comment: I would also suggest letting the PHP side build the actual HTML.  It's a lot easier to read and edit html in php files (or html files with embedded php) than it is to read and edit in javascript.  Generating complex elements (such as forms with many children) to inject to the dom leads to more errors than it ever leads to success .

Comment: Yep, but actually the random function is needed cos the client wants that everytime the page loads it charges a random image/project. Sorry, gdoron, how do i accept answers?

Comment: Dan, you mean building it as an ajax response and not as a success event?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using HTML 5 data- Attributes.

Here is an article that explains them: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Basically just add something along the lines of

`data-projectID="' + data.data[i].projectId + '"`

and then look for that attribute in your php script.